# Cycle2 Slider - goto Slide issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I am using the Cycle2 slider and am wanting to only show the first slide once, so I added some code to skip over the initial slide if it is the next slide and instead go to the second slide and continue the slideshow from there. But when it skips to the second slide, the all of the slides go invisible for a moment and when they reappear it is on the fourth slide. Any ideas what's going on here? My code is below.

```
<script>
$('.cycle-slideshow').on( 'cycle-before', function( e, opts, curr, next) {
    if (opts.nextSlide == 0){
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('goto', 1);
    return false;
}
});
</script>
```